# How to go back to beginning of the line in (ex) command mode?

Tags: ex-command

The standard `CTRL-E` works to go to the end of the line but `CTRL-A` doesn't seem to work to go to the beginnig.

It would obviously be useful to quickly go to the beginning of line for example if one wanted to replace `w /path/to/file` in with `w! /path/to/file`.

Is there a key to go to the beginning of the line in command mode and if so how does one map it to `CTRL-A`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `<C-b>` to go to the beginning of the line; from [`:help c_CTRL-B`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-B):

```
CTRL-B or <Home>                                c_CTRL-B c_<Home> c_Home
                cursor to beginning of command-line
```

If you want, you can use this to map it to `<C-a>`:

```
:cnoremap <C-a> <C-b>
```

Related: [How can I use Readline shortcuts in the vim command line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6040/51)